# Object to ByteString \ Byte Array

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

New to GooglePubSub and trying to use its feature under .net framework application. I am trying to publish one of c# object over pubsub bus using Publishasync API (https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/api/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.PublisherClient.html) Just wondering does google pub sub provides any handy method to convert c# object to bytestring, which can be easily deserialized on receving end by applications like Java or .NEt core.
One of the option I know to do this is by using protobuf-net. Is there is any other way to easily convert c# object to bytestring (or byte array) in language neutral way.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PubSub doesn't provide additional methods of converting C# objects to byte strings.

Converting objects to bytestrings, in a *cross-language way* is a general problem with many existing solutions.  Here are some solutions:

1. [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial) (as you mentioned.)
2. [Thrifty](https://thrift.apache.org/)
3. [CapnProto](https://capnproto.org/) looks like it's no longer maintained.  :-(

This Wikipedia article compares many solutions:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats